# How to create a Boolean Mask which preserves a column?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean, mask

for example:
say I have

```
x = np.array[['positive','a'],['negative','b'],['positive','c'], ['negative','d']]
```

and I want a new array with the value

```
v = [['positive','a'], ['positive','c']]
```

How could this be done? Thank you your time!

Comment: @n404 Maybe you should examine numpy function also....np.array is a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correcting the syntax:

```
In [359]: x = np.array([['positive','a'],['negative','b'],['positive','c'], ['ne
     ...: gative','d']])
In [360]: x
Out[360]: 
array([['positive', 'a'],
       ['negative', 'b'],
       ['positive', 'c'],
       ['negative', 'd']], dtype='<U8')
```

Just select "rows" with indices:

```
In [361]: x[[0,2],:]
Out[361]: 
array([['positive', 'a'],
       ['positive', 'c']], dtype='<U8')
```

An equivalent boolean mask:

```
In [362]: mask=np.zeros(4,bool)
In [363]: mask[[0,2]]=True
In [364]: mask
Out[364]: array([ True, False,  True, False])
In [365]: x[mask,:]
Out[365]: 
array([['positive', 'a'],
       ['positive', 'c']], dtype='<U8')
```